# TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Tags: pandas

I have the following Panda dataframe:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbVlY.png)

and I need to group the columns per quarter using the resampling function

```
df_copy=df_copy.resample('Q',axis=1).mean()
```

however when I apply the function I get the following error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Please, can you help me to group the years into quarters? this function is just driving me crazy, I also previous to applying the function I change the type of the years(2000-1,2000-2,2000-3.....) from String to DateTime in order to re-sample.